# Django css file is not working

Tags: html, css, django

I'm new in Django and get problem.
I have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
```

at my settings.py, have Project/mainapp/static folder and css/header.css inside that folder.
Also i have

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/header.css' %}" type="text/css">
```

at my header html. Browser tries localhost/static/css/header.css but find nothing there. What am i doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Maybe you need to include app port number in url like: localhost:8080/static/...

Comment: does not help guyz. Already tried collectstatic, it makes a directory admin inside static, add admin files and this is it. Anyway i run deafalt server and it is supposed to work without collectstatic. Making STATIC_URL = 'localhost:8000/static/' didnt help also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your settings as below:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), )
```

`BASE_DIR` is global variable you can find in same settings.py which points to project's working directory. `static` is your folder inside root directory of your app.

And load `static` in template instead of `staticfiles` like below:

```
{% load static %}
```

Comment: Note: this settings will only work in django if DEBUG is set to True otherwise you need to serve staticfiles with apache or nginx

Comment: have less than 15 reputation, cant upwote now, sorry. Just chosen as the answer! Thank you!